# How to use async instead of threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I have currently worked on a web crawler where I have one python instance for each store/news I want to monitor. For every store it contains between 0 - infinity links that I want to monitor.

I have currently coded my code in threads and I have quickly realized that if I have 200 links to monitor or 5 different python instance (for different store) and each instance contains 30 links to monitor, that would be 5 py instance x 30 links = 150 thread instances that is running and I do realize that this is not quite good for the computer to run that many threads heavily.

```
import random
import time
from typing import List

import cloudscraper
import kthread
from loguru import logger
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

STORE_THREADS = {}
all_found_products: set = set()

proxies = [
    "http://test:29360",
    "http://test:29361",
    "http://test:29362",
    "http://test:29363",
    "http://test:29364",
    "http://test:29365",
    "http://test:29366",
    "http://test:29367",
    "http://test:29368",
    "http://test:29369",
    "http://test:293610"
]


def from_page(url, session):
    infos = []
    # Session proxies could be not working to your enviorment, comment if needed
    # session.proxies = {"https:": random.choice(proxies)}

    with session.get(url, timeout=10) as rep:
        if rep.status_code in [200, 404]:
            doc = HTMLParser(rep.text)
            for product in doc.css('table.search-result-table, article.product-wrapper'):
                link = product.css_first('div.product-image > a, td.search-articlenumber > a').attributes.get('href')
                infos.append(link)
    return infos


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Monitor and check if there is new products uploaded on the page
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
def monitor_feed(url):
    session = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
        browser={
            'browser': 'chrome',
            'mobile': False,
            'platform': 'windows'
        }
    )

    # Scrape and return
    feed: List = from_page(url=url, session=session)

    for add_url in feed:
        all_found_products.add(add_url)

    while True:
        feed: List = from_page(url=url, session=session)

        for new_url in feed:
            if new_url not in all_found_products:
                logger.info(f"Found new URL {new_url} from {url}")
                all_found_products.add(new_url)

        logger.info(
            f'[Products Found: {len(feed)}]'
            f'[Total Products Found: {len(all_found_products)}]'
            f'[URL: {url}]'
        )
        time.sleep(300)


def initialize_threads():
    # Mock data for one store, this link can be between 0-infinity
    FOOTISH_URLS = [
        "https://www.footish.se/searchresults?pagesize=20&searchstring=yeezy",
        "https://www.footish.se/sneakers?sortby=2&sortdirection=1",
    ]

    # FIXME Replace random.choice to feed links found in DB
    for url in random.choice([FOOTISH_URLS]):
        STORE_THREADS[url] = kthread.KThread(target=monitor_feed, args=(url,))
        STORE_THREADS[url].start()
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize_threads()
```

Currently I have coded it in thread and I would like to move over to async but the problem is that I am in need of using the "Cloudscraper" lib which is sync.

I got a suggestion to do something like this:

```
well it is
if you have a pool of presolved
~300 urls being pooled at once
where you have a pool of all your proxies
then you have a "working" pool
of presolved
and if 1 gets burnt replace it
etc
thats a thread in its own right mantaining the pre-solves
then you just hand that pool off to your async
```

however I do not get it on how I can do it and I belive there might be a better solution than the suggestion I got.

My question is, how can I use async instead of threading where I minimize the problem of having epic resource intensive threads?

Comment: 150 threads are no problem with a simple task and a modern computer. You can also use a thread pool to limit the number of tasks. But then you should avoid sleeping in the workload function.

Comment: @KlausD. well but this can be increased by alot, what if we are up to over 500 threads then? The sleeping is that I dont want to DDOS the website of course  :D

Comment: Still not an isssue but I already gave an alternative: Use a thread pool, for example https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: @KlausD. but how can I use thread pool if `monitor_feed` will never return, that means if I have 10 links and I use a thread pool of max 5 workers, then it will just do the first 5 and never reach the other 5 that is waiting then since we use a `while True` inside the monitor_feed?

Comment: That is what you have to change, if the threads get too many. You should have a master thread that dispatches the work instead of the threads handling everything on their own.

Comment: @KlausD. I agree with you but how can I be able to do that? I can't think of a solution on how to do it

Comment: @KlausD. How come that it is ok with over 500 threads on a modern computer? How do you know it wont use too much resources etc etc?

Comment: Try it.  500 threads is nothing - the box I am using now has 1213 threads existing.  Of course, very few are actually running at any instant:)

Comment: @MartinJames Is it so? Dont you see any slowdown on resources or high resources usage?

Comment: Nah - that's normal.  Between sundry OS accessories, antivirus, adBlocker, Torrent client and all the other 'normal' stuff loaded at startup, and 'real' apps that I deliberately loaded like development IDE and this Firefox, 1000+ threads is normal, and fine.  If I am temporarily not using stuff, it gets paged out.  When using the box, like now, I don't notice any effect at all because nearly all those threads are blocked on I/O, inter-thread comms, sleeping or nortready/running for some other reason.

Comment: You don't have to believe me - you can test it:)  Make 500 threads in a loop and block them all on some event/semaphore.  Run it, wait a couple seconds for everything to get created etc, then carry on using your box as usual.  See any effect?